# C++Builder 10.4/11: Help wanted to resolve fatal error "Invalid object file 'altsvc.o'" when compiling 64-bit Windows application

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder

I am attempting to port a 32-bit program to 64-bit, using the CLANG compiler within C++Builder 10.4/11. However, when C++Builder attempts to link the EXE it generates the following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(3988,5): error : Fatal: Invalid object file 'altsvc.o'

I cannot find a file called "altsvc.cpp" anywhere in my source files or in the C++Builder library file folders. It is not listed in the executable's project (.cbproj) file either.

Has anyone encountered this error before and know what causes it?

Comment: But can you find `altsvc.o` anywhere on the paths the linker is searching or in the build tree ? Typical cause on porting to different architectures - there was a source for `altsvc.cpp`, which at onetime was built.  `altsvc.cpp` was deleted as not needed leaving `altsvc.o` this is still being linked if a wildcard was used for the linker.  Now the link fails because of wrong architecture.

Comment: One altsvc.o (altsvc.c) is part of the curl library. Is your project using that?

Comment: I have searched all the paths that the linker points to and cannot find altsvc. However, the comment from @dratenik has solved the problem for me. Thanks for your suggestions anyway

Comment: The problem *was* caused by the cURL library. Although I have the 64-bit lib linked in to one of my DLLs, it appears that me EXE also need to have that lib linked in (not sure why, since it only referennces the DLL, but hey ho ...). Thanks for the suggestion about cURL